# Reading character by character with bash read

Tags: bash, readline

I've been trying to use bash to read a file character by character.

After much trial and error, I have discovered that this works:

```
exec 4<file.txt 
declare -i n
while read -r ch <&4; 
     n=0
     while [ ! $n -eq ${#ch} ]
           do  echo -n "${ch:$n:1}"
               (( n++ ))
          done
     echo "" 
     done
```

I.e., I can read it line by line and then loop through each line char by char.

Before doing this, I had tried:
`exec 4<file.txt &&  while read -r -n1 ch <&4; do; echo -n "$ch";  done`
but it would *skip all whitespaces in the file*.

Could you please explain why? Is there a way to make the second strategy (i.e. reading char by char with bash's read) work?

Comment: Set [`IFS`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/IFS) to nothing to have whitespaces survive the word-splitting.

Comment: Tried that with IFS='', but I guess it had to be just IFS=. Thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to remove whitespace characters from the `$IFS` parameter for `read` to stop skipping leading and trailing ones (with `-n1`, the whitespace character if any would be both leading and trailing, so skipped):

```
while IFS= read -rn1 a; do printf %s "$a"; done
```

But even then bash's `read` will skip newline characters, which you can work around with:

```
while IFS= read -rn1 a; do printf %s "${a:-$'\n'}"; done
```

Though you could use `IFS= read -d '' -rn1` instead or even better `IFS= read -N1` (added in 4.1, copied from `ksh93` (added in `o`)) which is the command to read one character.

Note that bash's `read` can't cope with NUL characters. And ksh93 has the same issues as bash.

With zsh:

```
while read -ku0 a; do print -rn -- "$a"; done
```

(zsh can cope with NUL characters).

Note that those `read -k/n/N` read a number of *characters*, not *bytes*. So for multibyte characters, they may have to read multiple bytes until a full character is read. If the input contains invalid characters, you may end up with a variable that contains a sequence of bytes that doesn't form valid characters and which the shell may end up counting as several *characters*. For instance in a UTF-8 locale:

```
$ printf '\375\200\200\200\200ABC' | bash -c '
    IFS= read  -rN1 a; echo "${#a}"'
6
```

That `\375` would introduce a 6-byte UTF-8 character. However, the 6th one (`A`) above is invalid for a UTF-8 character. You still end-up with `\375\200\200\200\200A` in `$a`, which `bash` counts as 6 *characters* though the first 5 ones are not really characters, just 5 bytes not forming part of any character.

Comment: Thanks. Simple and beautiful. I actually tried something to this end (modifying the IFS variable), but it kind of didn't work for me so I ended up with that concoction of mine (Unnecessary playing with file descriptors, etc.).

Comment: Interestingly, it looks like using `read -rN1` instead solves the newline issue and thus eliminates needing to provide a newline as default when printing `$a`.

Comment: Just **FTR** I'm reading 4118 line 20 MB file. Using `read -n1` (char by char) takes **4 min** 51 seconds and heats laptop to 90 degrees. Using `read -r` (line by line) takes **1.3 seconds** and laptop stays at 54 degrees with dual-fans silent.

Answer (score 2):

This is a simple example using `cut`, a `for` loop & `wc` :

```
bytes=$(wc -c < /etc/passwd)
file=$(</etc/passwd)

for ((i=0; i<bytes; i++)); do
    echo $file | cut -c $i
done
```

[KISS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle) isn't it ?

Comment: If that is KISS, then what is a pure `bash` solution: `file="$(</etc/passwd)"; bytes="${#file}"; for ((i=0;i<bytes;i++)); do echo "${file:i:1}"; done`?

Comment: Thanks to both.  Yeah, if i have to resort to getting those characters from lines, I might as well get them from the whole file. I find sch's solution the most KISS, though.

Comment: @manatwork That is a good, simple solution.  Even so, it seems to me like the above answer using a read loop is quite a bit faster for some reason.  Maybe substrings in bash are fairly slow?

Comment: @krb686, actually the entire `bash` “It's too big and too slow.” according to its man page's BUGS section. But even so, is still faster to slice a string in memory than to read a file again and again for each character. At least on my machine: http://pastebin.com/zH5trQQs