# How can I make POSIX shell and awk read input character by character instead of line by line?

Tags: linux, shell, awk

How can I make POSIX shell and awk read input character by character instead of line by line?

I'm making a transliteration app from romaji to japanese kana and I want to process input instantly character by character into awk.

I don't know the proper way to do this without needing to press return or enter before awk processes the characters.

Comment: Not sure how awk factors into this but see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/49582/reading-character-by-character-with-bash-read and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8725925/how-to-read-just-a-single-character-in-shell-script for some shell info. Or just google something like "Unix shell read 1 character at a time", there's lots of examples.

Comment: How attached are you to awk? That's not a common way to use awk and I don't think a POSIX awk (maybe GNU awk with extra work) can be convinced to react to a single character immediately.

Comment: I'm pretty attached to sh+awk for this project. If I can get it to work cleanly even with ugly code I'd be happy. the reason for awk is that it's installed by default on all Linux+UNIX systems and I wouldn't need to install extra libraries or dependencies to run the program.

Comment: I would be open to ideas though. I don't know what other language would meet the above goals. ideally, I'd just git clone my repo and it would work on any Linux/macOS/UNIX system.

Comment: Isn't one-character-at-a-time pretty problematic for this task anyway? One-to-three characters will matter and in some cases are only disambiguated retrospectively, so you have to maintain state anyway. Portable awk is fundamentally line-oriented and so not very suitable, but it seems like the problem itself needs further specification.

Comment: thanks for pointing that out Michael Home and stop being evil. I think I might actually just re-implement this project in C or another language. I'd still be curious as to how this might be accomplished in sh+awk as a curiosity, but I didn't realize how convoluted it would be.

Comment: Perl and python are available on pretty much any non-embedded unix-like system and are easier to get running on Windows.

Answer (score 1):

In shell scripting, you can manipulate the TTY state using the `stty` tool.

Firstly, `stty -g` produces a character string which snapshots the current state. Before doing anything else, capture the output of this and save it somewhere. Later you can pass that string as the only argument to `stty` to restore the TTY settings.  This string does not require quoting; the POSIX standard requires `stty -g` to produce a representation that requires no quoting in shell scripts.

`stty raw` is one way to get into a raw mode in which character-at-a-time input is possible.

```
savetty=$(stty -g)
stty raw
...
stty $savetty
```

It may be a good idea to use the `trap` command to set up a handler which will restore the `tty` settings even if the script exits somewhere or is interrupted.

Now, suppose we have this `stty` dance wrapped around some Awk code. Without loss of generality, let's do that outside of Awk. How can we make Awk read one character at a time?

Awk can only read lines with its implicit scanning strategy or the `getline` operator. There is no `getchar`. Ah, but lines actually means **records**. And in GNU Awk, we have two tools at our disposal not in the POSIX standard:

1. The `RS` variable may consist of more than one character, in which case it is a regular expression.
2. The `RT` variable holds the piece of text that was matched as the record terminator.

Behold:

```
$ awk  'BEGIN { RS = "(.)" } { print NF, RT }'
How now brown cow.
0 H
0 o
0 w
0  
0 n
0 o
0 w
0  
0 b
0 r
0 o
0 w
0 n
0  
0 c
0 o
0 w
0 .
```

If we use the regular expression `(.)` (match any character) as the record separator, we get empty records that contain no fields at all, and the character which terminated the empty record is available in `RT` in GNU Awk.

Unfortunately, this does not quite work. When we integrate it into a complete program:

```
#!/bin/sh

trap 'stty $ttysave' EXIT INT TERM
ttysave=$(stty -g)

stty raw -echo

awk  'BEGIN { RS = "(.)" }
      RT ~ /q/ { exit }
      { printf("[%s]", RT) }'
```

this exhibits the problem that Gawk's record-delimiting regex machine is reading one character ahead. For instance, if we want to quit immediately by typing `q`, that `q` is not good enough. Even though a record could be delimited at that point, and `RT` could be set to `q`, Gawk invokes another `read` on the TTY to read a character, and only then does it dispatch the record.

Thus, we have to resort to something very ugly, like looping in a `for` or `while` loop and invoking the `dd` utility:

```
#!/bin/sh

trap 'stty $ttysave' EXIT INT TERM
ttysave=$(stty -g)

stty raw -echo

awk  'BEGIN { cmd = "dd bs=1 count=1 2> /dev/null"
              for (;;)
              { cmd | getline ch
                close(cmd)
                if (ch == "q")
                  exit
                printf("[%s]", ch) } }'
```

Comment: It will need quoting if `IFS` is set to a non-default value. (Try e.g. with `IFS=:`) There are no characters that are always safe.

Comment: That takes care of making the terminal send input to awk immediately. But I don't think any implementation of awk supports processing input one character at a time.

Comment: @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil' OK, you are on; I will add that to the answer.

Comment: @ikkachu `IFS` must never be set to a non-default value without being restored. What if someone sets `IFS=e`. Then you must quote every variable expansion that could contain e. Do you? About the only use case for setting `IFS` is to call `set` for splitting something into the positional parameters.

Comment: POSIX states "If the `-g` option is specified, `stty` shall write to standard output the current settings in a form that can be used as arguments to another instance of `stty` on the same system". "Arguments", plural. This means some implementations of `stty` may generate/require *multiple* arguments, so `$savetty` *must not* be quoted. Then `IFS` matters. The specification does not explicitly state what `IFS` to use. I guess it's reasonable to assume the value of `IFS` should be the default. So don't quote `$savetty` but make sure `IFS` is the default.

Comment: `dd bs=1 count=1` reads bytes, but the awk script needs to process multibyte characters. Romaji aren't limited to ASCII.

Comment: @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil' While that is true, OP can code that him or herself.  I've written an interactive listener for a Lisp implementation, in which you can input kana, so I know how this works. At the lowest level, it still reads byte-at-a-time from the TTY. It has to accumulate the UTF-8 characters itself. This fundamentally no different from how it has to accumulate the ANSI escape sequences to handle like arrow keys. There are going to be major difficulties coding a UTF-8 decoding state machine in Awk; I wouldn't use this language for the task, myself.